# Using footnotesize in ctable package

Tags: tables, fontsize, ctable

I have a long table requiring the use of a `\footnotesize`. The table is made using a `\ctable` package as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\ctable[
    caption = {cap1},
    label   = {tab:tabu},
        pos = ht,
]{lcc}{
  \tnote[$\ast$]{footnote is here}
}{                             \FL
Variable & Estimate & p-value \ML
var1  &   4.4   &   0.02 \\
var2 \tmark[a]  &   2.4   &   0.01  \\
var3  &   -6.2  &   0.08 \LL
}

\end{document}
```

I want to know how to use `\footnotesize` to help fit the contents my table in a page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ctable` provides the `doinside` key-value option, so simply use `doinside=\footnotesize`. (The caption font size won't be affected.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\ctable[
    caption = {cap1},
    label   = {tab:tabu},
    pos = ht,
    doinside = \footnotesize,
]{lcc}{
  \tnote[$\ast$]{footnote is here}
}{                             \FL
Variable & Estimate & p-value \ML
var1  &   4.4   &   0.02 \\
var2 \tmark[a]  &   2.4   &   0.01  \\
var3  &   -6.2  &   0.08 \LL
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not usually recommended to change the fontsize to fit the table, but if you must you can just surround the table in braces and put `\footnotesize` inside. In fact, `ctable` provides a hook for this `doinside` (as lockstep points out in his answer), so this is actually the better way. This will not affect the size of the caption, which is probably what you want. Since you are typesetting numerical data with signs and decimals,  you probably not use the `c` column type but instead use a column type more suited for this sort of data.  The `S` column provided by the `siunitx` package does a nice job of this. Since it tries to automatically recognize numerical data, it's helpful to enclose column headings in braces

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepacakge{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\ctable[
    caption = {cap1},
    label   = {tab:tabu},
    pos = ht,
    doinside=\footnotesize
]{lSS}{
  \tnote[$\ast$]{footnote is here}
}{                             \FL
Variable & {Estimate} & {p-value} \ML
var1  &   4.4   &   0.02 \\
var2 \tmark[a]  &   2.4   &   0.01  \\
var3  &   -6.2  &   0.08 \LL
}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Just before your comment, I used \begin{footnotesize} ... and accomplished what I wanted.